# How to assign a value to model property once HTML.RadioButtonFor is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to `MVC`. Currently I have a strongly typed view, and I use two `Html.RadioButtonFor` for labels, the codes are somethings like:

```
<label class="radio">
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Incoming, true)IncomingItems</label>
 <label class="radio">
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Incoming, false)OutgoingItems</label>
 <input type="hidden" id="isIncomingItem" value = "@Model.Incoming" />
```

What I want is to set model.Incoming to be true when the first radio button is selected or set it to false, and then I want to use this model property right away in the view( assign this value to `"isIncomingItem"`) before the entire form is submitted to server.

Do you guys have a idea about how I could achieve it. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Incoming` property is already filled with the selected value and it will be available for the action method. And if you want to set the same value in the hidden field, try as following

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Incoming,new { id = "isIncomingItem"})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used JQuery to get the value of isIncomingItem in action, but what I got was always "false" which is default of m.Incoming. It seemed to me that Incoming property was not updated. Is it true that the model property is updated only after being posted the server.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use jQuery, doing something like:

```
$("[name='Incoming']").change(function () {
    $("#isIncomingItem").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I bind "isIncomingItem" to a action, like updateFunctions.BindAddItem("#btnAddId", "#inputEqIDMan", "#isIncomingItem");  But in jQuery, I always got the same incoming value, it seemed it was not updated.